# How can we use python to get sentences from Wikipedia?

Tags: python

```
import Wikipedia

result = Wikipedia("India", sentences = 2)
print(result)
```

It gives me an error. Please can you resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import wikipedia
 
result = wikipedia.summary("India", sentences = 2) 
print(result)
#use Wikipedia in small case and use summary
```